# “Input string was not in a correct format” error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a code for Updating the Row in a gridview, but the issue is that, when I edit and update the Row it is giving me error as Input string was not in a correct format. At the below line of Code:-

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Active);
```

Please see my code for your reference:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPostData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
    CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" CssClass="hoverTable"
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdPostData_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="grdPostData_RowEditing"
    OnRowDataBound="grdPostData_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="grdPostData_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="grdPostData_RowUpdating">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></ControlStyle>

            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="30"
            ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></ControlStyle>

            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Category" ItemStyle-Width="50">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostCategory" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
                    AutoPostBack="false">
                    <%-- <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>--%>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></ControlStyle>

            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="eDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"
                    runat="server" Width="15px" Height="15px" CausesValidation="False"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="15%"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" CausesValidation="false"
            ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png"
            UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
            <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>

            <ItemStyle Width="15px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Result Found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Also see the CS code:-

```
protected void grdPostData_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    bool IsUpdated = false;
    //getting key value, row id
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(grdPostData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    //get all the row field detail here by replacing id's in FindControl("")..
    GridViewRow row = grdPostData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string PostTitle = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
    string Postdesc = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    //   string ddlPostCategory = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).SelectedValue;
    string Active = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_Post SET title=@title, description=@description, active=@active WHERE Id=@Id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 155).Value = PostTitle;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 99999999).Value = Postdesc;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Active);

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        IsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        conn.Close();
    }
    if (IsUpdated)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('page updated sucessfully');window.location ='csrposts.aspx';", true);
        BindGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        //Error while updating details
        grdPostData.EditIndex = -1;
        //bind gridview here..
        //GET GDATA FROM DATABASE AND BIND TO GRID VIEW
    }
}
```

I know this is not worth a question, tried but couldn't find. Please help.

Code for Dropdownlist aspx:-

```
<div class="controls">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActiveInactive" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp wd"
        runat="server" Style="width: 100%" ValidationGroup="AddNew">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Active"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="InActive"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the debugger and tell us the value of `Active`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The value is coming `null`

Comment: `TextBox.Text` _never_ returns null. The property [returns an empty string instead](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,92b4f85cd223169c,references).

Comment: So your problem is solved. You can use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() method to verify whether value is Null,Empty or WhiteSpace. If it is not than continue with operation

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Agree with you. So what can I do in that case ?

Comment: @Pawan: I want the value to get updated but it is not allowing me, I think i am not putting proper code to work it out.

Comment: @RahulSutar: tell us what value it actually is.

Comment: You probably want to validate the textbox, ensure that it has a value and it is an int. You can use` RequiredFieldValidator` and `CompareValidator` for this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It is a dropdownlist which has values `Active` and `InActive`. See the edited question for your reference:-

Comment: @RahulSutar: that makes no sense. You've said that the error is raised at `Convert.ToInt32(Active)`. `Active` is in a different column than the dropdownlist. If you want to use the selected-value of the DropDownList instead use: `((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlActiveInactive")).SelectedValue`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ok let me try with your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is a dropdownlist which has values Active and InActive

If you actually want to get the `DropDownList`'s selected value use `FindControl`:

```
var ddlActive = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlActiveInactive");
int active = -1; // or whatever
if(ddlActive.SelectedValue != "")
    active = int.Parse(ddlActive.SelectedValue);
// ...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Int)
    .Value = active != -1 ? active : System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` function to remove the whitespaces and the convert it to `int`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Active.Trim());
```

Comment: : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'trim' and no extension method 'trim' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) error is coming